# Is there a way to pass list of enums to step in cucumber 4.x and java

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

let's say I have example enum class

```
public enum Name { FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME;}
```

and I have a such step

```
 Then followed name types are listed:
      | FIRST_NAME |
      | LAST_NAME  |
```

in which I want to pass List like

```
  @Then("^followed name types are listed:$")
  public void followedNameTypesAreListed(List<Name> nameTypes){...}
```

I'm currently migrating to cucumber 4.x and what i figured out is that i can register custom DataTableType like

```
typreRegistry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(Name.class,
        (TableCellTransformer<Name>) Name::valueOf)
```

but doing it for every single enum class doesn't sound very efficient, isn't there any other way to handle list for any enum class?

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to do this would be to us an object mapper as the default cell transformer. The object mapper will then be used in all situations where a cell is mapped to a single object and no existing data table type has been defined.

You could use `jackson-databind` for this.

In Cucumber v4:

```java
package com.example.app;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistry;
import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistryConfigurer;

import java.util.Locale;

public class ParameterTypes implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return Locale.ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        typeRegistry.setDefaultDataTableCellTransformer(objectMapper::convertValue);
    }
}
```

And in v5:

```java
package com.example.app;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.cucumber.java.DefaultDataTableCellTransformer;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class DataTableSteps {

   private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

   @DefaultDataTableCellTransformer
   public Object defaultTransformer(Object fromValue, Type toValueType) {
       return objectMapper.convertValue(fromValue, objectMapper.constructType(toValueType));
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay. I set default transformers for DataTableCell, DataTableEntry and Parameter as it was described here:
[link](https://cucumber.io/blog/open-source/migrating-to-cucumber-jvm-4-2/)
however with such default DataTableEntry transformer I lose possibility to map list of enums, but without it I'm not able to pass object base on data table so e.g 

 Then followed object is listed
| name | color | city |
| John | black| London|


Is there a way to have both those features working?

Comment: A single list is ambiguous when both default table cell and entry transformers are defined. Preference is given to entries (with a header). In that case you'll explicitly have to define each enum.